# SXA Overlay slow to close

Tags: sxa

has anyone else noticed that if you open and close an overlay multiple times on a page, it gets slower and slower to close?
I have a simple "Link" which opens a overlay - this works fine every time, but for each time I click the link, and close the overlay, it takes longer and longer to close.

This is Sitecore 10.1, SXA 11200.

Comment: Is it happening in both content editor and experience editor and for all items? Also can you please add maybe some printscreens/details to the question?

Comment: This is happening on the published site. I have a Link, which points to an "overlay" item. The Link opens the Overlay with the setting "Open link in overlay".